# What does browser.bootstrap stand for in dukescript projects?

Tags: dukescript

Every time I generate a new [dukescript](/questions/tagged/dukescript) project using [knockoutjs](/questions/tagged/knockoutjs) sample code, this appears in some comment: `browser.bootstrap`

```
<!-- ${browser.bootstrap} -->
```

Does it have some use? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has some use. It's a placeholder. If you wan to run your project in a browser with TeaVM or bck2brwsr the required javascript code will be injected here. In all other projects it doesn't do anything. If you remove it, the project won't run in the browser.